# Failed to update work status Exception in Python Cloud Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Python Cloud Dataflow job that works fine on smaller subsets, but seems to be failing for no obvious reasons on the complete dataset.

The only error I get in the Dataflow interface is the standard error message:

> A work item was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service.

Analysing the Stackdriver logs only shows this error:

> Exception in worker loop: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 736, in run deferred_exception_details=deferred_exception_details) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 590, in do_work exception_details=exception_details) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 167, in wrapper return fun(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 454, in report_completion_status exception_details=exception_details) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 266, in report_status work_executor=self._work_executor) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/workerapiclient.py", line 364, in report_status response = self._client.projects_jobs_workItems.ReportStatus(request) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/clients/dataflow/dataflow_v1b3_client.py", line 210, in ReportStatus config, request, global_params=global_params) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 723, in _RunMethod return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 729, in ProcessHttpResponse self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 599, in __ProcessHttpResponse http_response.request_url, method_config, request) HttpError: HttpError accessing https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects//jobs/2017-05-03_03_33_40-3860129055041750274/workItems:reportStatus?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '400', 'content-length': '360', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Wed, 03 May 2017 16:46:11 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "(2a7b20b33659c46e): Failed to publish the result of the work update. Causes: (2a7b20b33659c523): Failed to update work status. Causes: (8a8b13f5c3a944ba): Failed to update work status., (8a8b13f5c3a945d9): Work \"4047499437681669251\" not leased (or the lease was lost).", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } } >

I assume this `Failed to update work status` error is related to the Cloud Runner? But since I didn't find any information on this error online, I was wondering if somebody else encountered it and does have a better explanation?

I am using `Google Cloud Dataflow SDK for Python 0.5.5`.

Comment: What's are your pipeline source(s) and sink(s)?

Comment: The 2 sources are avro-files on GCS and the sinks are TFRecord files on GCS.

Comment: Do you have a job ID available to share? Any details about what your pipeline is doing that you could describe?

Comment: The Job ID: 2017-05-07_13_10_15-6017060458892203962, the pipeline is a preprocessing job for ML Engine. It starts from 2 sets of AVRO files, combines these and then generates TFRecords from the combined data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One major cause of lease expirations is related to memory pressure on the VM. You may try running your job on machines with higher memory. Particularly, a highmem machine type should do the trick.

For more info on machine types, please check out the [GCE Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types)

The next Dataflow release (2.0.0) should be able to handle these cases better.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to run the job with higher memory machines (and also Dataflow version 0.6.0)! Is there any roadmap where I can find the expected release date for Dataflow 2.0.0? I didn't find it yet.

Comment: Dataflow 2.0.0 was released in mid june : )