# Pipeline inputs 8 billion lines from GCS and does a GroupByKey to prevent fusion, group step running very slow

Tags: etl, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, bigdata

I read 8 billion lines from GCS, do processing on each line, then output. My processing step can take a little time and to avoid worker leases expiring and getting below error; I do a `GroupByKey` on 8 billion and group by id to [prevent fusion](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#fusion-optimization).

> A work item was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the
>   worker eventually lost contact with the service. The work item was
>   attempted on:

The problem is GroupByKey step is taking forever to complete for 8 billion lines even on a 1000 high-mem-2 nodes.

I looked into the possible cause of slow processing being; large size of each value generated per key by GroupByKey. I don't think that's is possible because out of 8 billion inputs, one input id cannot be in that set more than 30 times. So clearly the problem of HotKeys is not here, something else is going on.

Any ideas on how to optimize this are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to prevent fusion? What is _"to avoid worker leases expiring"_? Something doesn't sound right when you need to use 1000 nodes for only 8 billion rows. We regularly process upwards of 10B rows with just 50VMs in a few hours (GCS -> Dataflow -> BigQuery)

Comment: One reason I am trying to "avoid fusion" is because cloud support team said.  "It looks like the workers of your pipeline take too much time performing the stage computation and by the time they report back the status of their work item, the lease has already expired. "

Comment: According to this thread this error I have been getting might just be due to memory pressure on the VMs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835866/failed-to-update-work-status-exception-in-python-cloud-dataflow

Comment: Did you try running your pipeline without the GBK and with highmem machines? Any luck that way?

Comment: I increase the node type from high-mem-2 to high-mem-4 and this problem went away. I will be posting a detailed answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to solve this problem. There were a number of incorrect assumptions here on my part about [dataflow wall times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835866/failed-to-update-work-status-exception-in-python-cloud-dataflow). I was looking at my pipeline and the step with highest wall time; which was in days, I thought is the bottleneck. But in Apache beam a step is usually fused together with steps downstream in the pipeline, and will only run as fast as the step down the pipeline runs. So a wall time that is significant is not enough to conclude that this step is the bottleneck in the pipeline. The real solution to the problem stated above came from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43984874/384554). I reduced the number of nodes my pipeline runs on. And changed node type from high-mem-2 to high-mem-4. I wish there was an easy way to get memory usage metrics for a dataflow pipeline. I had to ssh into VMs and do JMAP.